# Access files generated by Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a web application using R Shiny and deployed it with the shinyapps.io using the free mode. The problem that I have is that my application generates a set of .txt files which I need to download them after my application finishes. Is there any way that I can access those generated files? I have seen my shinyapps.io control panel, but I did not find any way to have access to my files.

Can I use Filezilla or a similar tool to have access to those generated files?

Comment: One workaround would be to use the Download button in your web application